# Why do a rollback instead of exiting the session by writing return in the catch clause?

Tags: sql, transactions, return, try-catch, rollback

Maybe I am thinking to specific but i cannot get a satisfying answer to following question:

If I have a Transaction, wrapped in a try block, that might fail and i want to be rolled back,
can I or should I not exit via a return in the catch block?
As i understand if a session is exited SQL SERVER rolls back that transaction anyway.

Such a stored procedure would be executed via an SSIS package.

Do i have to issue a Rollback? SSIS might wait longer for a return...

The structure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [example]
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;  --Best Practise: messages from SP are are disabled; XACT_ABORT every failure results in rollback;


BEGIN TRY
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 -----------------Update---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    UPDATE [example]

-----------Inserts---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        INSERT INTO [Stg].[example]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
END TRY 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN CATCH
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
END CATCH

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT OFF;
```

My alternative catch block would be:

```
BEGIN CATCH

RETURN

END CATCH
```